# Append line after [stuff] using the sed command

Tags: linux, sed, append

Effectively I am trying to insert a line of text directly after a stanza heading in a configuration file "testfile" kind of like this:

```
[default]

[stuff]

[stuff_test]

[end]
```

The goal is to insert a line of text "variable = 1" directly after and only after [stuff].  This is the desired output of "testfile"

```
[default]

[stuff]
variable = 1

[stuff_test]

[end]
```

When I try using the append function of sed:

```
sed -i "/[stuff]/ a variable = 1" testfile
```

I get the following:

```
[default]
variable = 1

[stuff]
variable = 1

[stuff_test]
variable = 1

[end]
```

My question is why is it inserting text in the first three stanzas and not just the second stanza as I intended?  I tried using exact match but I might have the context wrong? The following other efforts have been tried:

```
sed -i "/\<[stuff]\>/ a variable = 1" testfile

sed "/\<\[stuff\]\>/ a variable = 1" testfile
```

This will not insert any text into the file. How do I get sed to insert only after the "[stuff]" stanza?

Comment: awk 'NF > 0 && $0 ~ /\[stuff\]/{$0=$0" Variable = 1"} 1' file
 . with awk as an alternate

Comment: Thanks for trying Chet. Your command does effectively the same thing as my first example sed command only it doesn't insert it into the following line but directly after on the same line as the first three stanzas and will not insert into the file: ie: [default] Variable = 1

Comment: can you add a sample output. i couldn't figure out much

Comment: Sample output is included in the question, is it not clear enough?

Comment: got it now . answered

Comment: It is not a good idea to add things like "please help" to your question, it's even officially encouraged to edit and remove that kind of noise, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions - you're already asking, no need to say that you'd like somebody to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address `/[stuff]/` is interpreted as a regular expression, i.e., matches any line that contains any of the characters `s`, `t`, `u` or `f`. To avoid interpretation as a bracket expression, you have to escape the square brackets:

```
sed -i "/\[stuff\]/ a variable = 1" testfile
```

Answer (score 2):

with **awk**

```
awk 'NF > 0 && $0 ~ /\[stuff\]/{$0=$0RS"variable = 1"} 1' file
```

check if `NF: number of field` is greater than zero and matched `stuff regex`, then append the line with `RS: record seperator`, which is newline with expected value

Comment: Works so I up-voted you but was really looking for a sed implementation.  Thanks for your help!